# Query with a calculated field based on another table in Access

Tags: sql, ms-access, calculated-field

I have two Microsoft Access tables with the following values:

```
Devices

| N    | Desc   | O | P |
+------+--------+---+---+
| 3560 | ABC    | 0 | 0 | <-
| 3559 | DEF    | 0 | 1 |
| 3558 | GHI    | 1 | 0 |
| 3557 | JKL    | 1 | 0 |
| 3548 | MNO    | 0 | 0 | <-
| 3549 | PQR    | 0 | 0 | <-
| 3540 | STU    | 0 | 0 | <-

Notifications

id | N    | Email       |
---+------+-------------+
1  | 3559 | a@dom.loc   | <-
2  | 3548 | a@dom.loc   | <-
3  | 3548 | b@dom.loc   |
4  | 3547 | b@dom.loc   |
5  | 3549 | b@dom.loc   |
```

I would like to extract all the `Devices` records with `O = 0` and `P = 0` and add a **calculated field** named **Subscribed**. This field must be `True` only if the same `N` exists in the **Notifications** table with an `Email` that I supply as parameter and `False` otherwise.

Having for example `Email = a@dom.loc` parameter (i.e. hardcoded in the SQL for this purpose), then this should be the required result:

```
| N    | Desc   | O | P | Subscribed |
+------+--------+---+---+------------+
| 3560 | ABC    | 0 | 0 | False      |
| 3548 | MNO    | 0 | 0 | True       |
| 3549 | PQR    | 0 | 0 | False      |
| 3540 | STU    | 0 | 0 | False      |
```

How can I do this query in Access considering that the two tables might be large in the future?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably I missed the subquery SQL, this works:

```
SELECT Devices.N, Devices.Desc, Devices.O, Devices.P,
(SELECT Count(*) FROM Notifications
WHERE Notifications.N = Devices.N
AND Notifications.Email = "a@dom.loc") > 0 AS Subscribed
FROM Devices
WHERE ((Devices.O=0) AND (Devices.P=0))
```

EDIT: After @iDevlop comment I was able to create the LEFT JOIN variant correctly, thanks!

```
SELECT Devices.N, Devices.Desc, Devices.O, Devices.P, Not IsNull(Id) AS Subscribed
FROM Devices
LEFT JOIN (SELECT Notifications.N, Notifications.Id
FROM Notifications
WHERE (Notifications.Email = "a@dom.loc")) AS qNotif
ON Devices.N = qNotif.N
WHERE ((Devices.O=0) AND (Devices.P=0));
```

Comment: If your tables are large (>100 000 recs) I think you will get a better perf using a LEFT JOIN